# tinymce flask-wtf form input not validating

Tags: flask, tinymce

My limited tinymce editor is formatted on my html page as:

```
 {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='tinymce/tinymce.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#body',
      toolbar: 'fontsizeselect',
      fontsize_formats: '8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 16pt 18pt 24pt 36pt 48pt',
      menubar: 'edit format',
      menu: {
      edit: { title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste | selectall | searchreplace' },
      format: { title: 'Format', items: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript'},
       },
      width: "100%",
    });
</script>
```

It has the following form behind it:

```
class TenderForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(('Username'), [validators.DataRequired()])
    title = StringField(('Title'), [validators.DataRequired()])
    body = TextAreaField(('Input'), [validators.DataRequired()])
    user_id = IntegerField(('id number'), [validators.DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField(('Submit'))
```

And this is the route:

```
@app.route("/write", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def write():
    form = TenderForm()
    print(form.errors)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        id = request.form['user_id']
        title = request.form['title']
        body = request.form['body']
        timestamp = datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
        new_post = Post(user_id = id, timestamp = timestamp, title=title, body = body)
        db.session.add(new_post)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for("latest"))
    flash("form not validated")
    return render_template('write.html', form = form)
```

Nothing happens when I hit submit.  But if I remove the tinymce editor my input submits to the database as intended.  Please can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?